# How to select a Certificate using the Windows Security's Confirm Certificate popup in C# console or WinForms application?

Tags: c#, certificate, digital-signature, x509

I want to write a C# console or WinForms application to add digital signature to a PDF file using a Certificate .PFX file. Currently, I am able to sign PDF files using a PFX certificate from a folder in the file system, using iText7 and BouncyCastle libraries.

But I need to ask the user to choose a Certificate at run time from the list of installed certificates in the system.

Specifically, I want to display the Windows Security's Confirm Certificate dialog box, and sign using the certificate selected by the user. I want to show the popup shown below:

[image: Windows Security Confirm Certificate dialog box]

My specific question is:
How can I trigger the Windows Security's Confirm Certificate dialog box, and how can I read the certificate selected by the user?

EDIT 1:
If I use X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection method, I get a different popup as shown below. This is different from what I want.

[image: X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection` which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui.selectfromcollection?view=netframework-4.8).

As @Crypt32 mentioned in the comments i felt the neccessity of adding code example how to use the api. I was wondering how @AllSolutions managed to get that UI window using the same API. It seems the UI changes with the `selectionFlag` parameter.

```
var store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
var collection = store.Certificates;
var cert = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(collection, "Select", "Select a certificate to sign", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
```

Comment: When I use the X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection, I get a different kind of dialog box. It is not exactly the same which I have shown in my question. I have posted screenshot of the dialog box that I get under EDIT 1 in my question

Comment: You have to set `SingleSelection` flag in `selectionFlag` parameter of `SelectFromCollection` method call. This will invoke the first UI dialog. When you use `MultiSelection`, second UI is displayed.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I have a follow-up question: How to achieve the same using BouncyCastle library? For signing PDF files using iText, I need to use BouncyCastle library. So either I want this certificate selection screen using BouncyCastle, or else how can I convert the X509Certificate2 of .NET library to Pkcs12Store of BouncyCastle?

Do you want me to post a separate question for this?

Comment: I have posted 1 followup question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918431/how-to-construct-pkcs12store-from-x509certificate2