# How to construct Pkcs12Store from X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, bouncycastle, x509

I have an object of System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.
I want to construct an instance of Pkcs12Store (Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs) using this object.

I tried:

**Approach 1:**

```
        public Pkcs12Store GetPkcs12Store(X509Certificate2 cert, string password)
        {
            byte[] rawdata = cert.RawData;
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(rawdata);
            Pkcs12Store pk12;

            pk12 = new Pkcs12Store(memStream, password.ToCharArray());
            return pk12;
        }
```

In this approach, I am getting the exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger'.
```

**Approach 2:**

I tried:

```
        public static Pkcs12Store GetPkcs12Store(X509Certificate2 cert, string password)
        {
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bcCert;
            bcCert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);

            pk12 = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder().Build();
            X509CertificateEntry certEntry = new X509CertificateEntry(bcCert);
            pk12.SetCertificateEntry(bcCert.SubjectDN.ToString(), certEntry);

            AsymmetricKeyEntry keyEntry = new AsymmetricKeyEntry(bcCert.GetPublicKey());

            return pk12;
        }
```

In this approach, I do not get the exception I was getting earlier, but then the Pkcs12Store returns false for IsKeyEntry.

```
            string alias = null;

            foreach (object a in pk12.Aliases)
            {
                alias = ((string)a);
                if (pk12.IsKeyEntry(alias))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ICipherParameters pk = pk12.GetKey(alias).Key;
```

So the code fails at the line `ICipherParameters pk = pk12.GetKey(alias).Key;`

**Approach 3:**

```
        public static Pkcs12Store GetPkcs12Store(X509Certificate2 cert, string password)
        {
            Pkcs12Store pk12;
            byte[] rawdata;
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bcCert;
            rawdata = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password);            
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(rawdata);
            pk12 = new Pkcs12Store(memStream, password.ToCharArray());
            return pk12;
        }
```

In this approach, I get the error:
`Key not valid for use in specified state.` at the statement `cert.Export...`

Comment: Check [here](https://7thzero.com/blog/bouncy-castle-create-a-basic-certificate).

Comment: I checked the article. But if I construct Pkcs12Store as described in the article, then the Pkcs12Store object is not able to find any KeyEntry. The IsKeyEntry method returns false for all the Aliases

Comment: I referenced that article because it is describing how to add a certificate to a store. You are trying to create a store by feeding the certificate raw bytes.

Comment: Well, I converted the certificate raw bytes to a Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate, and then constructed the Pkcs12Store. But it is not constructed properly, as the store method IsKeyEntry returns false for all the Aliases

Comment: this is because `X509Certificate2.RawData` doesn't include the private key. You have to use `X509Certificate2.Export` to export it to PFX byte array that includes encrypted key material.

Comment: I have changed my code to ```DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);``` Do I still need to use ```X509Certificate2.Export```?

Comment: Ideally ```DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);``` should take care of converting the .NET certificate to BouncyCastle certificate with all its keys, right?

Comment: If I try: ```rawdata = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx); memStream = new MemoryStream(rawdata); pk12 = new Pkcs12Store(memStream, password.ToCharArray());``` then I get the error: ```Key not valid for use in specified state.```

Comment: Well, you didn't export it with a password so you can't give `Pkcs12Store` a password when you read it in. Go ahead and use the two-argument form of `Export` and make the second argument the password.

Comment: I get the same error even if I add the 2nd argument. Key not valid for use in specified state. I did some more search and found that the key is not exportable because the certificate was not created with marking the key as exportable. So the question is if I have a digital signature certificate from a USB etoken device, how can I add digital signature to a document without being able to extract the private key.

Comment: If you want to use BouncyCastle, then you have to find out how to access your eToken from BC code. You cannot use PKCS12 store in this case. Maybe, your iText library accepts other certificate objects than from PKCS12 and which doesn't require private key material export.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you resolve this?

Comment: I have still not been able to resolve it. If you ever find an answer, please post here.

Comment: @AllSolutions I have the same problem, did you resolve this?

Comment: @Adnan, unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when you try to import the certificate to the store and MARK the key as EXPPRTABLE and then it will work like a charm

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).